# Ask a question and told it's answered when it's not

Tags: discussion

OK - so I ask a question and someone updates saying it's been answered already and it's marked as a duplicate when it's not and the post they refer to doesn't solve the problem at all.  So now the questions doesn't get answered.

What are you supposed to do as I updated the question with revised information stating that the problem is still outstanding and different but now no one's helping.  How do I get the duplicate removed?

Comment: Got a link?....

Comment: Also, it's best to *edit* your question saying it isn't a dupe, that puts it into the reopen queue. Very few people (if anyone) will see your comment. I've voted to reopen for now.

Answer (score 3):

Give us a link, and we will re-open the question if it really doesn't answer yours.

A bunch of people deciding it is a duplicate closes a question. Another bunch can come in and say it is not, and reopen it.

EDIT:

[I found your question here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/403859/how-to-control-lightdm-power-saving-preferences#403859).

The duplicate status is correct, in the sense the question is the same, but if the answer doesn't work, you have every right to request a re-open. I just cast my vote.